# How do I create a function with a function in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a function called jaccard that works something like this

```
def jaccard(doc1, doc2):
    inter = len(np.intersect1d(doc1, doc2))
    union = len(np.union1d(doc1, doc2))
    jaccard = float(inter)/union
    return jaccard
```

Except I only want it to take one parameter and have the other parameter hard coded into the function.

I want to write a function that will generate this function with the hard coded parameter because I need to use it with thousands of parameters.

```
def jaccard(doc2):
    inter = len(np.intersect1d(['Work with us --- The Missing Slate Magazine'], doc2))
    union = len(np.union1d(['Work with us --- The Missing Slate Magazine'], doc2))
    jaccard = float(inter)/union
    return jaccard
```

So I want to generate a function like this.

The reason I want this is because I want to apply it to a column of a Pandas DataFrame. The data frame contains a list of strings. I want to find the jaccard distance for each of them with the hard coded parameter in the function.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I don't understand.  Didn't you just answer your own question?  Put the strings in the function and you are good to go.  What am I missing?

Comment: I want to make a function that returns that function below. I will clarify with edits.

Comment: Uh, what are the contents of the column in your data-frame?

Comment: Just use a decorator? Or a wrapper function?

Comment: [`functools.partial(jaccard, doc1)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial)?

Comment: In general, though, functions are just objects, like anything else. You can think of a function definition `def my_func(): ...` as sugar for `my_func = function()`.  So, you can just use a `def` statement inside a function, and `return my_func`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create closures in python. For instance

```
def jacard(doc1):
    def _jacard(doc2):
        inter = len(np.intersect1d(doc1, doc2))
        union = len(np.union1d(doc1, doc2))
        return float(inter)/union
    return _jacard
```

then:

```
prepared_func = jacard(doc1)
```

afterwards:

```
results = map(prepared_func, some_array_of_doc2s)
```

partial argument binding using functools in this case is a shorthand for creating a closure with argument doc2 bound.

```
prepared_func = functools.partial(jaccard, doc1)
```